# Which is the inverse Fourier transform of $ \frac{w^2}{1+iw^2}$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

Which is the inverse Fourier transform of $\frac{w^2}{1+iw^2}$?

I want to know step-by-step which function is the inverse Fourier Transform of these $\frac{w^2}{1+iw^2}$ in a simplest-to-work-form, since I have a result from Wolfram-Alpha but it relates derivatives of the "absolute value" function, for which I don't know how to manipulate it to more friendly functions like step-functions or similar, and hopefully, without delta functions (since I looking for a bounded function in time).

Please work with the following definitions of the Fourier transform:
$$F(iw) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t)\,e^{-iwt}\,dt $$
and
$$f(t) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(iw)\,e^{iwt}\,dw $$

*Using $F(iw)$ instead of $F(w)$ is just notation, I am following the definitions used in the book "Signals and Systems, 2nd Edition" (Alan V. Oppenheim, Alan S. Willsky, with S. Hamid) [[1](https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/program/Oppenheim-Signals-and-Systems-2nd-Edition/PGM10192.html)].*

Beforehand, thanks you very much.

---

**Added later**

Wolfram-Alpha says [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Fourier+transform&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22FourierTransformCalculator%22%2C+%22transformfunction%22%7D+-%3E%22sqrt%282*pi%29%2F%282*pi%29*w%5E2%2F%281%2Bi*w%5E2%29%22&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22FourierTransformCalculator%22%2C+%22variable1%22%7D+-%3E%22w%22&assumption=%7B%22C%22%2C+%22Fourier+transform%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22Calculator%22%7D&assumption=%7B%22F%22%2C+%22FourierTransformCalculator%22%2C+%22variable2%22%7D+-%3E%22t%22) that for real $t$, and using that $\sqrt{t^2} \cong |t|$:

$$ f(t) = \frac{e^{-\frac{|t|}{\sqrt{2}}}}{2\sqrt{2}}\left\{\left(\cos\left(\frac{|t|}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{|t|}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)+i\left(\cos\left(\frac{|t|}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{|t|}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)\right\}$$
**Is this right??**

Comment: Unfortunately, no way to escape delta-function.
$$\frac{\omega^2}{1+i\omega^2}=-i\,\frac{1+i\omega^2}{1+i\omega^2}+\frac{i}{1+i\omega^2}=-i+\frac{1}{\omega^2-i}=-i+\frac{1}{(\omega-e^{\frac{\pi i}{4}})(\omega+e^{\frac{\pi i}{4}})}$$
Applying the inverse Fourier transform, the first term gives $-i\delta(t)$, while the second is regular and can be evaluated, for example, via contour integration.

Comment: @Svyatoslav Wolfram-Alpha gives an answer with no delta functions, I have incorporated to the question... Is Wolfram-Alpha mistaken?

Comment: I'm afraid it is. Take, for instance, $t=0$. The integrand is even; $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{\omega^2}{1+i\omega^2}d\omega=\infty$

Comment: Sorry, corrected typo. 

The regular term coincides with the Wolfram-Alpha solution. Closing the integration contour in the upper half-plane (for $t>0$) and evaluating the residue at $\omega=e^{\frac{\pi i}{4}}$
$$f(t)=−i\delta(t)+\frac{1}{2}e^{-\frac{t}{\sqrt2}}e^{\frac{it}{\sqrt2}+\frac{\pi i}{4}}$$

Comment: This is really strange that Wolfram-Alpha does not catch the delta-function, though it gives the delta-function for (inverse) Fourie transform of $[1]$

Comment: @Svyatoslav I have already found a few mistakes in W-A so I take its results with caution (I have made a few question because of that already if you want to check)... Maybe in the section were the wrong solution is given, instead of saying ~"for real variable t" in that case is "for positive variable t"... I am totally rusty about complex integrals (last time I calculate a contour integral was in university about a decade ago), so I didn´t check if the delta function get somehow canceled by a term in the lower half-plane... but if the converse transform make it appear surely is a mistake of WA

Comment: If $t<0$, you should close the contour in the lower-half plane (and you get $|t|$ in the general solution for $t\in R$), but the term with delta-function appears in both cases: delta-function is even and $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{i\omega t}d\omega=2\pi \delta(t)$ for  $t\in R$. Both terms in the general solutions are, therefore, even - this is visible from the initial integral (just make the change $t\to-t$).